# What will be the effect on a rigid body if two like unequal parallel forces act on the body?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics

What will be the effect on a rigid body if two like unequal parallel forces act on the body? Will the body translate or rotate or both? If they rotate, with respect to which point will they rotate?[image]

Here I have mentioned 'Like Unequal Parallel' forces, not 'Unlike Unequal Parallel' forces.

Comment: I am confused about this one too. That's why asked separately. Please, help me if you can.

Comment: Calculate the torque about the center of mass. If it is zero, body will not rotate.

Comment: No, the torque about the center of mass is not zero. Then, How can I find the point about which the body will rotate.

Comment: Refer to theory on ICR in a good book

Comment: Please, suggest me a good book

Answer (score 0):

If the torque is non-zero the body will rotate and translate. However, if the torque is zero the body will only translate with an acceleration:
$a=\frac{F_{1}+F_{2}}{m}$.

Comment: If they rotate, with respect to which point will they rotate?

Comment: @Hisab I am not sure but I think: If the the two forces are parallel $F_{1}r-F_{2}(L-r)=0$ where L is the lenght of the segment that connects the two points where the two forces act.

Comment: Draw two lines. One touching the tails of both force vectors; the other touching the heads. The point where they meet is the ICR.

Comment: I have drawn two lines as you said. But they don't meet. Have a look: http://tinypic.com/r/ohnzvl/9

Comment: Use this formula, $r=\frac{F_{2}L}{F_{1}+F_{2}}$ the distance r is calculate from the tail of $F_{1}$ and $L$ is the total lenght of the segment touching the tails of the forces

Comment: You should extend those lines Hisab and they'll meet somewhere to the left(in your figure). As long as the forces are unequal the lines would always meet.